# Define media queries as variable

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following simple `HTML` and `CSS` code with `media queries` which you can also find in the `JSfiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/92o0wbne/1/):

```css
/* Screenwidth as variable */

:root {
  --min-width: 1041px;
}


/* homepage */

@media screen and (min-width:1041px){ 
 
 .homepage {
 height: 500px;
 width: 400px;
 }
 
}
  
  
@media screen and (max-width:1040px){ 
   
 .homepage {
 height: 300px;
 width: 100px;
 } 
   
}


/* faq */

@media screen and (min-width:1041px){ 
 
 .faq {
 height: 800px;
 width: 600px;
 }

}
  
  
@media screen and (max-width:1040px){ 
   
 .faq {
 height: 700px;
 width: 550px;
 } 
   
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
Here goes content of homepage.
</div>

<div class="faq">
Here goes content of faq.
</div>
```

As you can see in the code I will have different pages on my website and they should have a different size depending on the device that is accessing the website. The `media queries` itself work perfectly already.

---

However, since I will have a lot of those `media queries` within in my CSS and I might want to change them to different sizes to test and try things it would be great to have the `min-width` and the `max-width` as `variable` within the `:root` part of the CSS.

Do you know if this is even possible and if yes how I have to change my code to make it work?

Comment: maybe you should look into SASS. In SASS you can define the query as string which gives you a lot more freedom than CSS alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use the css native variables in media query.

The :root, that is the  element is a top-level parent. The other child elements can inherit from the root but the media query is not an element,

This can't be done through css.
you can use preprocessors like sass to accomplish this.